# Some Math, and more functions in define statements

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I'm trying here to make some math, in Quanity, and balance. But that function in define, don't do anything to balance, and quanity. When I print them they are still the stock.

```
Ballance = 7000 # 7K DEMO
# SANDELYS
Indica_WEED_QUANITY = 600
AMAZON_QUANITY = 18
STEAM_GIFT50_QUANITY = 4
# Price
STEAM_GIFT50_PRICE_PER1 = 50 # Each
Indica_WEED_PRICE_PER1 = 8
Amazon_Prime_PRICE_PER1 = 25 # Each

def PickForShopItem():
    ShopPick = int(input("~ PRODUCT ID = "))
    if ShopPick == 1:
        clear()
        while True:
            Pasirinxm = input("Would You like to continue buying ~ Indica WEED KUSH * ?\n* Y/N: ")
            if "Y" in Pasirinxm or "y" in Pasirinxm:
                clear()
                BuyKiekis = int(input("~ How many you would to buy of " + Indica_WEED_NAME + "?\n "))
                Indica_WEED_QUANITY - BuyKiekis # Atimam Ir paliekam sandari mazesni
                Bendra_Suma = ( BuyKiekis * Indica_WEED_PRICE_PER1)
                print(Bendra_Suma)
                Ballance = 500
                print(Ballance - Bendra_Suma)
                print("Sandelio Kiekis po pirkimo " + str(Indica_WEED_QUANITY))
                print(Ballance)

                break
            elif "N" in Pasirinxm or "n" in Pasirinxm:
                print("xuine iseina")
                break
            elif " " in Pasirinxm or len(Pasirinxm) < 1:
                print("PLease dont do shit")
                continue
                break
    elif ShopPick == 2:
        print("Darai")
    elif ShopPick == 3:
        print("hgelo")

Indica_WEED_NAME = "~ Indica WEED KUSH *
```

Comment: By default, assignments in Python will set values in the local scope, rather than affecting an outer scope from whence the variables came. I think this is to encourage a more functional programming style. (That is, functions should return a value, rather than changing global values.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your code snippet is not self-contained since you do not tell us the input that would show the error. Please show example input, desired output, actual output, and how the actual differs from the desired. Show the full traceback for any errors. In other words, read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For the love of god, please don't capitalize variable names. Use snake_case, not a combination of PascalCase, snake_case, and camelCase.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem you have is that:

```
Indica_WEED_QUANITY - BuyKiekis
```

does not update the variable "Indica_WEED_QUANITY" (and you have the same problem in the line `print(ballance - BendraSuma)`)

In Python, that statement will just work out a value, but you aren't telling the program to save or store it anywhere.  Do this:

```
Indica_WEED_QUANITY = Indica_WEED_QUANITY - BuyKiekis
```

Python also allows you to do this with a -= operator:

```
Indica_WEED_QUANITY -= BuyKiekis
```

will update Indica_WEED_QUANITY by subtracting the BuyKeikis amounts.